# How to get single record if the multiple records are on single ID?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

[In this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFQvm.png), 5 record are with id 80, but when i fetch them they all are coming but i want to show just one record only.

[image]

My rest code is below here

```
$data['query7'] = $this->ORB_Model->get_skilldash();

public function get_skilldash()
    {
        $this->load->database('orb');
        //$this->db->distinct('master_id');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('skills_tb', array('master_id' => $this->session->userdata('master_id')));    
        return $query->result();    
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

*Use `$query->row()` instead of `$query->result()`;*

```
public function get_skilldash()
{
    $this->load->database('orb');
    $master_id = $this->session->userdata('master_id');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('skills_tb', array('master_id' =>$master_id));    
    return $query->row();    
}
```

If you want a specific row returned you can submit the row number as a digit in the first parameter:

```
$row = $query->row(3);
```

Or Simply use it with  `$this->db->distinct();` do like this:

```
$this->load->database('orb');
$this->db->distinct();
$master_id = $this->session->userdata('master_id');
$query = $this->db->get_where('skills_tb', array('master_id' => $master_id));    
return $query->row();
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-rows